# kubectl timeouts when reaching a cluster in VPN

Tags: networking, vpn, kubernetes

I have a very strange issue - my kubectl cli cannot reach a cluster inside a VPN.

My context:

- os archlinux
- kubectl Client Version: v1.28.1 (latest)
- curl to the api endpoint works well from my pc
- opening the api in browser works too
- I even wrote a small go module that uses go_client transport that also works
- I tried downgrading the kubectl client to match the remote cluster version but it also does not work.

It seems that everything works **except** kubectl.

```
kubectl get pods --request-timeout='5s' -n my-ns -v=99
I0913 17:43:34.500572   60035 loader.go:395] Config loaded from file:  /home/alexander/.config/kube/config
I0913 17:43:34.501699   60035 round_trippers.go:466] curl -v -XGET  -H "Accept: application/json;g=apidiscovery.k8s.io;v=v2beta1;as=APIGroupDiscoveryList,application/json" -H "User-Agent: kubectl/v1.28.1 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/8dc49c4" 'https://172.16.10.10:6443/api?timeout=5s'
I0913 17:43:34.556074   60035 round_trippers.go:510] HTTP Trace: Dial to tcp:172.16.10.10:6443 succeed
I0913 17:43:39.503205   60035 round_trippers.go:553] GET https://172.16.10.10:6443/api?timeout=5s  in 5001 milliseconds
I0913 17:43:39.503231   60035 round_trippers.go:570] HTTP Statistics: DNSLookup 0 ms Dial 43 ms TLSHandshake 47 ms Duration 5001 ms
I0913 17:43:39.503241   60035 round_trippers.go:577] Response Headers:
E0913 17:43:39.503298   60035 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://172.16.10.10:6443/api?timeout=5s": net/http: request canceled (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
I0913 17:43:39.503312   60035 cached_discovery.go:120] skipped caching discovery info due to Get "https://172.16.10.10:6443/api?timeout=5s": net/http: request canceled (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
I0913 17:43:39.503398   60035 round_trippers.go:466] curl -v -XGET  -H "Accept: application/json;g=apidiscovery.k8s.io;v=v2beta1;as=APIGroupDiscoveryList,application/json" -H "User-Agent: kubectl/v1.28.1 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/8dc49c4" 'https://172.16.10.10:6443/api?timeout=5s'
```

My ip tables contain some "docker" related config that is using 172.17 and 172.18 ranges but not sure it has anything to do since "curl" and browser work properly..

Ip routes look ok too - traffic is routed via "tun" interface for the VPN.

```
default via 192.168.91.249 dev tun0 proto static metric 50
default via 192.168.10.254 dev enp5s0 proto dhcp src 192.168.10.134 metric 100
default via 192.168.10.254 dev wlp3s0 proto dhcp src 192.168.10.119 metric 600
172.16.100.0/24 via 192.168.91.249 dev tun0 proto static metric 50
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1
172.18.0.0/16 dev br-53500e17974d proto kernel scope link src 172.18.0.1
172.19.0.0/16 dev br-c1725b2d64cd proto kernel scope link src 172.19.0.1 linkdown
172.28.0.0/16 dev br-788b95918c9a proto kernel scope link src 172.28.0.1
192.168.10.0/24 dev enp5s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.10.134 metric 100
192.168.10.0/24 dev wlp3s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.10.119 metric 600
192.168.10.254 dev enp5s0 proto static scope link metric 50
192.168.91.1 via 192.168.91.249 dev tun0 proto static metric 50
192.168.91.249 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.91.250 metric 50
196.179.246.130 via 192.168.10.254 dev enp5s0 proto static metric 50
```

Comment: "request cancelled" doesn't sound like there's a problem making the TCP connection, but rather there's an authentication problem.

Comment: would't those explicitly be marked as 403 or 401 ? It is strange that te request does not return any headers

Answer (score 0):

After lots of tinkering we found out that the UDP network connection with the server gets clogged so we ended up adding "**mssfix 1400**" in the client config and it fixed things up.

If I understand correctly this value will force packets size over the tunnel and in our case fixed the issues.

There is also a "fragment" variable that many people recommend, but it was not activated on the server side.

For more info: https://openvpn.net/community-resources/reference-manual-for-openvpn-2-4/